# Platform Game - Getting the Object to adjust angle according to mouse position

Tags: java

What I basically am going for is a platform game where you can advance through stages by getting past enemies and such. You will get different weapons as you advance and pick things up. I would like for these different weapons you pick up to be able to be pointed in the direction that the mouse is currently at.

Since it's a little hard to example it right I found a video that pretty much shows exactly what I want but with a different sprites used.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8W7WSkQq5SU

So lets say this is the image I would use for one of the weapons:
[image: Pickaxe]

How would I go about adjusting it (pseudo code) to make the right point of the pickaxe be pointed in the same direction of the mouse?

I just looking for some pseudo code of how you may go about doing this the most efficient way and the smoothest way.

Comment: That depends on what you are using to render the game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Java `Graphics2D` then you have to use `AfflineTransform`. To do this first translate to the point of the axis of your pickaxe. Then you would rotate by the direction to the mouse which can be found using `atan2`. then you draw the axe so the offset matches the axis point.

Pseudocode:

```
#function drawAxe:
    translate(player.x, player.y);
    translate(pickaxis.x, pickaxis.y);
    rotation=toDegrees(atan2(mouse.y-player.y,mouse.x-player.x));
    rotate(roation);
    translate(-axisPointOnPickaxe.x, -axisPointOnPickaxe.y);
    drawImage(pickaxe.texture);
    IdentityMatrix();//[[1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,1]] or no transformation. i think you have to set a blank transform to do this in java efficiently
#endFunction drawAxe
```

Comment: Make sure you reset the transformation at the end or else your next draw call will be messed up.