# How do i rotate an image in JAVA?

Tags: java, image, rotation

I am getting started on a game in JAVA, which eventually shoould become an android app. anyway, i was wondering How to rotate an image (I eventually want to rotate a character to face the mouse, if you know how to do this it would be AMAZING!). Anyway, this is what i use to load the image:

```
ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("C:/image.jpg");
```

Any ideas? a rotate(Image image, int angle){} method would be great! 
If you knew how to rotate an image towards the mouse, that would be even better! Thanks for your time

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5925616

Comment: Yeah, also here: http://beginwithjava.blogspot.ca/2009/02/rotating-image-with-java.html Doing a google search before posting a question is usually a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't make a game with `ImageIcons`. you have to use gava.awt.Paint2D and paint to an image. then you can rotate it by setting the affline transform. here i answered a similar wuestion in more depth:

[Platform Game - Getting the Object to adjust angle according to mouse position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8762907/platform-game-getting-the-object-to-adjust-angle-according-to-mouse-position/8763062#8763062)

and a tutorial on java game programming in general:[here](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/java-game-programming-part-i-the-basics-r1262)

Comment: ah thanks! So what is the code to load and draw an image with java.awt.paint2d? and thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](http://www.javareference.com/jrexamples/viewexample.jsp?id=88) tutorial illustrate how to Rotate an image using Java 2D AffineTransform class .